# Data not correctly loaded with Node.js using express.js, fs and handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am kinda new to Node.js and experienced a strange behavior in my application.
At the beginning I am reading all uploaded files to my server using fs.readdir. Then the data is getting stored like this:

```
// Store all files and their data
var uploads = [];
var docData = [];

//read all files when server starts
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, items) {
  if(err) {
    console.log("Could not read files from directory " + dir);
  }
  else {
    uploads = items;
    uploads.forEach(function(item) {
      var path = dir + item;
      textract.fromFileWithPath(path, function( err, text ) {
        if(err) {
                console.log("Could not parse file " + path);
            }
        else {
          var val = {
            name : item,
            data: text
          };
          docData.push(val);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

So I store on the one hand the raw files and on the other hand the extracted text as json. But it does not load the files properly. It looks like the items are handed out to the frontend before these arrays are set, but I am not sure about this problem. The data is given to the frontend in this way:

```
app.get('/:search', function(req, res){
  var result = [];
  var invalidItems = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < docData.length; i++) {
    if(!(stringStartsWith(docData[i].name,"."))) {
      var index = i + 1 - invalidItems;
      result.push({id: index, doc: docData[i].name, count: 3});
    }
    else{
      invalidItems++;
    }
  }
  res.send(result);
});
```

And the handlebars template using jade looks like this:

```
// Template for search results
    script#result-template(type='text/x-handlebars-template')
      table#data.table.table-striped.table-bordered
        thead
          tr
            th ID
            th Document
            th Count
            th Delete
        tfoot
          tr
            th ID
            th Document
            th Count
            th Delete
        tbody
          |  {{#each this}}
          tr
            td {{id}}
            td
              a(href="/uploads/{{doc}}") {{doc}}
            td {{count}}
            td
              span.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash
          | {{/each}}
```

Is there any "clear" way to ensure that all the uploaded data has been parsed before sending the result to the frontend or do you think there is another stupid mistake?

Edit: The call in the js looks like that:

```
var needle = $('input[name=srch-term]').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:1234/"+needle,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (resp)
          var source   = $("#result-template").html();
          var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
          $("#result").html(template(resp));
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert('Error: '+e.text);
    }
  });
```

The complete app.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var multer = require("multer");
var fs = require('fs');
var textract = require('textract');
var app = express();
var upload = multer({ dest : './public/uploads'});
var dir = './public/uploads/';

// Store all files and their data
var uploads = [];
var docData = [];

//read all files when server starts
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, items) {
  if(err) {
    console.log("Could not read files from directory " + dir);
  }
  else {
    uploads = items;
    uploads.forEach(function(item) {
      var path = dir + item;
      textract.fromFileWithPath(path, function( err, text ) {
        if(err) {
                console.log("Could not parse file " + path);
            }
        else {
          var val = {
            name : item,
            data: text
          };
          docData.push(val);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});

require('dotenv').load();

var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: process.env.ES_HOST,
  log: 'trace'
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

app.use(multer({ dest: './public/uploads/',
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
    //add the current date to the filename to allow multiple uploads
    return filename + Date.now();
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
        console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...');
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
    console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path);
    //add the uploaded file to the stored files
    uploads.push(file);
    textract.fromFileWithPath(file.path, function( error, text ) {
      if(error) {
            console.log("Could not parse file " + file.path);
        }
      else {
        //add the uploaded file's text to the docData
        var len = dir.length - 2;
        var val = {
          name : file.path.substring(len),
          data: text
        };
        docData.push(val);
      }
    });
    }
}));

app.post('/upload',function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});

app.get('/:search', function(req, res){
  var result = [];
  var invalidItems = 0;
  console.log("Data = " + docData.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < docData.length; i++) {
    if(!(stringStartsWith(docData[i].name,"."))) {
      var index = i + 1 - invalidItems;
      result.push({id: index, doc: docData[i].name, count: 3});
    }
    else{
      invalidItems++;
    }
  }
  console.log("data; " + docData.length);
  res.send(result);
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

app.listen(process.env.SRV_PORT);

module.exports = app;

function stringStartsWith (string, prefix) {
  var res;
  try {
    res = string.slice(0, prefix.length) == prefix;
  }
  catch(err) {
    res = false;
  }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to check (even with `console.log`) the contents of `docData` inside app.get(...) callback?

If it's empty, then check if it's loading the files correctly (add other logging or just use debugger to see what's going on). Remember, that files are read asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer scareddragon. This is getting even more weird to me now. So I have basically 22 uploaded files. When I call something to search for the first time it displays me only 17, the next time 19, then always some more. After some requests it shows me 22 and then it starts printing to the console. The print was always 22!

Comment: It's because your program doesn't wait for the asynchronous calls to return before proceeding. It happens all the time to beginners in node. Show the rest of your code after `fs.readdir()` and no doubt we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you Nocturno, it is good to know that also others do these kind of mistakes. I just pasted the app.js on the top